# Testing state updations in an async method via React Testing Library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-testing-library

I have made a dummy component for the purpose of illustration. Please find the code below-

***Fetch.js***

```
import React from "react";
import { useFetch } from "./useFetch";

const FetchPost = () => {
  const { toShow, dummyAPICall } = useFetch();
  return toShow ? (
    <>
      <button onClick={dummyAPICall} data-testid="fetch-result">
        Fetch
      </button>
    </>
  ) : null;
};

export { FetchPost };
```

***useFetch.js***

```
import { useState } from "react";

const useFetch = () => {
  const [toShow, setToShow] = useState(true);
  const dummyAPICall = () => {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => {
        setToShow(false);
      })
      .catch(() => {
        setToShow(true);
      });
  };
  return {
    toShow,
    setToShow,
    dummyAPICall,
  };
};

export { useFetch };
```

I want to make an assertion here, that on click of the *Fetch* button my *Fetch component* shouldn't render on screen so, using React Testing Library, I am writing the test case like this:

```
import { fireEvent, render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import { FetchPost } from "../Fetch";
import { useFetch } from "../useFetch";

jest.mock("../useCounter");

describe("Use Fetch tests", () => {
  it("Should fetch results and show/hide component", async () => {
    useFetch.mockImplementation(() => {
      return { toShow: true, dummyAPICall: jest.fn() };
    });
    render(<FetchPost></FetchPost>);
    expect(screen.getByText(/fetch/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
    fireEvent.click(screen.getByTestId("fetch-result"));
    await waitFor(() =>
      expect(screen.queryByText(/fetch/i)).not.toBeInTheDocument()
    );
  });
});
```

My assertion:

```
expect(screen.getByText(/fetch/i)).not.toBeInTheDocument();
```

is failing as the component is still present. How can I modify my test case to handle this?

Comment: That's _asynchronous_, look at https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async/. Also you should `queryBy`, otherwise it'll error out when the component's not there rather than reaching the expectation.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I modified it using waitFor async method, but it's not working

Answer (score 1):

Mock network IO side effect is better than mock `useFetch` hook.  It seems you forget to import `waitFor` helper function from RTL package.

There are two options to mock network IO side effects.

1. [msw](https://mswjs.io/), here is [example](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/example-intro)
2. `global.fetch = jest.fn()`, don't need to install additional package and set up.

I am going to use option 2 to solve your question.

E.g.

`fetch.jsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useFetch } from './useFetch';

const FetchPost = () => {
  const { toShow, dummyAPICall } = useFetch();

  return toShow ? (
    <>
      <button onClick={dummyAPICall} data-testid="fetch-result">
        Fetch
      </button>
    </>
  ) : null;
};

export { FetchPost };
```

`useFetch.js`:

```js
import { useState } from 'react';

const useFetch = () => {
  const [toShow, setToShow] = useState(true);
  const dummyAPICall = () => {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => {
        setToShow(false);
      })
      .catch(() => {
        setToShow(true);
      });
  };
  return { toShow, setToShow, dummyAPICall };
};

export { useFetch };
```

`fetch.test.jsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { FetchPost } from './fetch';
import { fireEvent, render, screen, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';

describe('Use Fetch tests', () => {
  it('Should fetch results and show/hide component', async () => {
    const mResponse = { json: jest.fn() };
    global.fetch = jest.fn().mockResolvedValueOnce(mResponse);
    render(<FetchPost />);
    expect(screen.getByText(/fetch/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
    fireEvent.click(screen.getByTestId('fetch-result'));
    await waitFor(() => expect(screen.queryByText(/fetch/i)).not.toBeInTheDocument());
  });
});
```

Test result:

```sh
 PASS  examples/70666232/fetch.test.jsx (12.699 s)
  Use Fetch tests
    ✓ Should fetch results and show/hide component (51 ms)

-------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File         | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files    |   93.75 |      100 |   83.33 |   93.75 |                   
 fetch.jsx   |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 useFetch.js |      90 |      100 |      80 |      90 | 12                
-------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        14.38 s
```

package version:

```json
"@testing-library/react": "^11.2.2",
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.6",
"jest": "^26.6.3",
"react": "^16.14.0"
```